What would make only front-facing lens to become almost opaque?
I have owned an iPhone SE for about 3 years and only used the
front-facing camera for the first time yesterday.  The image was
hazy unless I point it in a direction with little sideways light.
I looked at the lens and it looked mildly opaque with some patterning on it. I found lots online about condensation, but this is when there is a temperature change. It has been warm and dry almost all the time and the problem seems to be consistent over a 24-hour period.
Furthermore, it only afflicts the front facing lens, which I find odd for condensation.
Unlike the rear-facing lens, the front-facing lens sits behind the
plate of glass covering the entire front of the iPhone.  No wiping
affects it.
I rarely use the front-facing lens, so I don't think it is worthwhile bringing it in for servicing.  Unlike the Q&A's I found online, my question is: What is the milky opaqueness likely to be?  As I describe above, the explanation of condensation doesn't fit the circumstances.
The iPhone has never been subjected to water.

You can control for condensation by keeping the device warm and dry. How often are you in a tropical / damp environment and then strongly air conditioned?

Let’s assume you don’t use a screen protector or have surface scratches around the front facing lens and have cleaned the glass with water dampened lint free cloth as Apple recommends.
Internally, all lenses have mechanical parts. Physical damage can cause internal elements to fall out of alignment, crack. Also, internal parts could also break and be loose enough to impinge upon the light path. Humidity can come in from the air, but unless you go from very humid to refrigerated and highly cooled environments, condensation is unlikely and temporary.
It’s almost always physical damage when the camera can’t make excellent photos. Usually it’s not the CCD that got damaged, but that is also possible with welding or solar / eclipse photography.
The rear cameras are generally more complex and fail than the front camera, but I’ve seen all of them fail and know Apple has a process to evaluate these in Apple support and people far more familiar with all the modes of failure and can let you know as they see the broken phones far more regularly than most of us.

Thank you, @bmike.  It's unlikely to be condensation.  I can't imagine what kind of impact could have caused this, but when I'm by a mall with an Apple store, I may pop in to at least determine the cause, even if I don't fix it.

Nice - you would know if it was condensation in all likelihood. I haven't tried remote service for this, but twice in store I had cameras replaced under warranty - once when I asked and once when the tech noticed it and offered a swap instead of just fixing the other issue I had. Good luck @user2153235
